# Can't write to the richTextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

I have this simple program :

```
private static System.Timers.Timer t3;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        t3 = new System.Timers.Timer(5000);
        t3.AutoReset = true; t3.Enabled = true; t3.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent3;

    }

    private void OnTimedEvent3(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        // MessageBox.Show("event raised");
        richTextBox1.Text = "t3 is elapsed ";// 
      }
```

**PROBLEM :** : Nothing appears in the `richTextBox1` after event is fired !  I have tried `MessageBox` and that works fine . what could be the problem ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the following:
The eventhandler of your timer is running on a different thread like your UI. You need to invoke the control like

```
if(richTextBox1.InvokeRequired == true)
{
    richTextBox1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
    {
      richTextBox1.Text = "t3 is elapsed "
    });
}
else
{
    richTextBox1.Text = "t3 is elapsed ";
}
```

to access it correctly. Thats because UI objects are related to their thread. Creating a MessageBox for example is possible out of every thread - because your Box is not existing already.

Comment: what's the difference between `richTextBox1` and `MessageBox`

Comment: yes great , but that didn't answer my question abouth the difference

Comment: Shure why not? The Messagebox is created during your handler, the richTextBox is already existing.

Comment: While it will work it should be noted that modifying the Text property will mess up any previous formatting. Not a big problem if the text is completely set but worthy to keep in mind..